# Why are some checkboxes missing from related products when they are downloadable?

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

We made a bunch of downloadable products. First made one, then duplicated it a bunch of times and changed what it links to.

Then for each downloadable product we added all the other downloadable products as "related products" so they show up in the left side-bar.

However only some of them have a checkbox next to them! We've gone through each product and clearly each of them has the exact same values for everything except the SKU and what the downloadable item is that they link to.

Can someone please explain why? Or how to fix this? It seems very random. Thanks.

We're on CE 1.8.1.0, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

In the default template there are a couple of checks that wrap these checkboxes:

```
<?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

These checks do the following:

1. isComposite - checks to see if the product is grouped or configurable,
2. isSaleable - checks to make sure that the product can be bought on the site,
3. getReuiredOptions - checks to see if the product has required options, if it does it cannot be directly added to the cart,

Comment: I know. But all of the products are identical except for the JPG image that is the downloadable aspect of them, and their title. Yet some have the checkbox, and some don't. Why would that be?

Comment: @CommaToast add some debugging into the template to see what these values are for these products.